# How to concatenate symbol in json rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**I  need to add '%' symbol in 'votes_count' field**

My controller,

```
@celebrity = Celebrity.includes(:category).order(votes_count: :desc)
```

I am counting the total votes here

```
  total_votes = Vote.count.to_f
```

changing the total no. of votes to percentage

```
  @celebrity.each do |celeb|       
    celeb["votes_count"] = (celeb.votes_count / total_votes * 100).round(2)
  end
```

here, I am changing into json

```
respond_to do |format|      
  format.json { render json: @celebrity.to_json(:include =>{:category => {:only => [:category]}})}      
end
```

My output is
[{"id":3,"name":"saravana","gender":false,"category_id":"1",**"votes_count":25**}]

My question is how can I add '%' symbol in votes_count

Comment: well, by the idea of MVC/rails, this is presentation - that needs to be done in templates or helpers....

Comment: and seriously, stop senseless tagging.

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply do this:

```
  @celebrity.each do |celeb|
    votes_count = ((celeb.votes_count / total_votes * 100).round(2))
    celeb["votes_count"] = "#{votes_count} %"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@celebrity.each do |celeb|       
  celeb["votes_count"] = (celeb.votes_count / total_votes * 100).round(2).to_s << "%"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@celebrity.each do |celeb|       
    celeb["votes_count"] = ((celeb.votes_count / total_votes * 100).round(2)).to_s + "%"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The real idea of MVC is to keep the data in its model - unformatted and present it, just how you need it, inside the view

Rails is giving you `number_to_percentage`
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_percentage

```
# view.html.erb
<%= number_to_percentage celeb.votes_count %>
```

// since i remember your last question:
**you need to save the percentage at the celibrity and save into DB**
if you dont you are loosing performance. imagine you have 1000 celibritys. for that you want to count every page requests 1000 times any percentages? that is stupid. if you just want to count the percentage of a current_selection of celibrities (lets say, the top3 and they are having 60/30/10 %) then your math is wrong since you relate the % to all votes and not to current_selection_votes_count)